# Bullets disappearing from bulleted list

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm trying to output a bulleted list (`<ul>`) in a LiteralControl, but a higher power doesn't like the bullets.  When I inspect an `<li>` element, it has inherited the style `list-style-type: none` from the extJS styles.  However, when I include the correct style in the `ul` tag, using the following code, the list gets rendered with an empty style attribute, e.g. `style=""`.  The same occurs if I place the style in the list individual list items.

```
sb.AppendFormat("<br />{0}<ul style=\"list-style-type: disk\">", Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried

```
list-style-type: disc
```

instead? (`disk` should be `disc`)